# Running bitcoind on VPS, won't speak to my web server

Tags: bitcoind

I have a VPS with bitcoind set up, synced the blocks and its all running fine. I have set up the bitcoin.conf file and allowed the IP of my web host server.

I am running a script on my web host that communicates to the wallet but it just won't connect!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to connect to http://INVENT_A_UNIQUE_USERNAME:INVENT_A_UNIQUE_PASSWORD@VPSIP:8333/' in /home/1234/public_html/gm/install/driver_test.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /home/1234/public_html/gm/install/index.php(16): jsonRPCClient->__call('getbalance', Array) #1 /home/1234/public_html/gm/install/index.php(16): jsonRPCClient->getbalance() #2 {main} thrown in /home/1234/public_html/gm/install/driver_test.php on line 61
```

Any suggestions? I have run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the wrong port. The RPC server listens on port 8332 by default, so try that. Port 8333 is for bitcoin node traffic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. It does take a while to do something now and looks like it is connecting but after 40 seconds or so it comes up with the same error as above. Are there any tests I can do to find out what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to restart the bitcoind whenever you make any changes to config file. Restart it by following command :

```
bitcoind stop
bitcoind
```

The content of the bitcoin.conf should be :

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=yourusername
rpcpassword=yourpassword
rpcallowip=123.123.123.123
```